# Log out a user and delete the account

Tags: linux, users, accounts

I am having a problem on the server (CentOS 6, Plesk 11.5) where a particular user is using a mass mailer and is blacklisting our IP address. I have tried to delete this user using:

```
/usr/sbin/userdel test
```

but it returns a message saying that the user is currently logged in. I thought ok, kill the process. So I tried:

```
pkill -u test
```

and also locked the account using:

```
passwd -l test
```

which will hopefully stop him logging into the system in future.

Still saying user is logged in. How can I log this user out to enable me to delete him off the system?

Comment: You may want to lock the account but keep it around. This could make it easier to find out what exactly that user has been doing (especially if there is a legal action).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First grep all the 'test' user's process and kill -9 all pid's then delete the user.

```
pgrep -u test
ps -fp $(pgrep -u test)
killall -KILL -u test
userdel -r test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
passwd -l <user>
```

doesn't stop all possible means of logging in.  For example, if they log in using `ssh` with public keys they can still login as they won't need  a password.

To stop the user logging in again, edit the `/etc/passwd` file and remove the user or change the 7th column to `/sbin/nologin`.

Run:

```
ps -u <user>
```

to see what process the user is still using and kill them all of them. You may have to use:

```
kill -s 9 <pid>
```

to force the process to stop.

Comment: ps -u <user> returns 21398 ?        00:00:01 sshd
21408 ?        00:00:08 sshd
21412 ?        00:00:03 sshd
21416 ?        00:00:00 sshd
21418 ?        00:00:00 sshd
21422 ?        00:00:01 sshd
21424 ?        00:00:03 sshd
21426 ?        00:00:03 sshd                                      do i just kill each process? thanks

Comment: Yes.  Kill them all.  Also ps -AF | grep <user> may show a few more as it will show processes with the username in their arguments.

Comment: For those of us scared to touch `/etc/passwd` directly, `sudo /usr/bin/chsh -s /sbin/nologin baduser` also works (`chsh`: change shell).

Answer (score 2):

`passwd -l <user>` does not disable the account.as gareth said the user may still can login using another authentication token such as SSH key.
to disable this account you should use 
`usermod --expiredate 1` this set the account expire date to 1970.
Now you should kill all processes the user is started.
running:

`$pgrep -u Foo` will print all processes that the user Foo is started.
running:

`$kill -9 <pid>` will sent `SIGKILL` signal which kill that process. Now
Run:

`$pgrep -u Foo | xargs kill -9`

this will get all process ids of user Foo and kill them all.

OR:

`$kill -9 -u Foo`

Comment: The usermod worked for me. I had an account that was passwordless that I initially couldn't delete. I added a password and I still couldn't delete it. Whenever I killed the user's process, a new one showed up and it seemed endless. After using usermod and expiredate, that seemed to stop it from creating a new process and so I could delete the account.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried killing all the user's processes with the SIGKILL?

```
pkill -KILL -u username
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested numeral, but whe I run command ps -u <user> to check, the processes are still running. Thanks

Comment: That's weird. SIGKILL and SIGABORT can't be ignored. Honestly not sure.

Comment: @user1532468 - did you run the commands as root?

Comment: @Wilf yes I run as root

Answer (score 0):

```
userdel -rf username
```

An error will pop up but this will delete the user permanently. You can check it in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: This does not log the user out first.